# How to UNLOCK rotation of the iPad 2 non retina

Tags: ios, ipad

At the bottom of iPad screen, when I swipe up and that pop up appears, there's no picture of rotation lock. Then in settings under General there is a USE SIDE SWITCH TO:  Lock Rotation  (blue check). How do I unlock rotation? I click on the blue check but it doesn't disappear.

EDIT: Every app I click on that used to rotate orientation, now don't rotate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Lock Rotation** and the **Mute** Under the **USE SIDE SWITCH TO:** act as radio buttons.

Selecting one deselects the other.

Depending on which one is selected determines what the side switch does.

Either **Mute** or  **Mute** or **Lock Rotation**.

The side switch is either On (showing an orange dot ) or off  (NOT showing an orange dot )

In Mute mode:

- side switch ON = silent
- side switch OFF = sound

In Lock Rotation mode:

- side switch ON = No Rotation
- side switch OFF = Rotation

The Control Center's  (when you swipe up) button that is used for  **Mute** or **Lock Rotation** will also change to either a **Mute** or **Lock Rotation** button depending what is selected in the settings.

So you have full control regardless of how you are setup.

Comment: When iPad is in Lock Rotation, no app rotates but there's sound.
When iPad is in Mute and not Lock Rotation. Now appropriate apps rotate but there's no sound.

How do I make it that the apps rotate and there is also sound?

Comment: Select Lock rotation in the menu. And have the side switch set to off (not showing orange)

Comment: I don't see a side switch on/off button. Under USE SIDE SWITCH TO: it only lets me check LOCK ROTATION or MUTE. I can't press anything else

Comment: The side switch is a physical switch at the Top right edge of the iPad